# How do I detect the number of distributions in a set of data?

Tags: distributions, python, population

I'm trying to detect subpopulations of data in a set of data.  The problem is that the data may have more than one subpopulation and the subpopulations may not be normally distributed.  For example, the data could look like this....

[image]

The Y axis is the count and the X axis is the value.  What I want is to determine the number of subpopulations and their peak values.  The programming language I'm most familiar with is Python, however, my methods have been less than successful.  It becomes problematic because in the example I showed there is a subpopulation with two peaks.  My method looks for peaks and valleys so in this example it would identify three subpopulations even though there are actually two.  I'm new to statistics so I was wondering if anyone here could suggest a way to detect subpopulations of data.

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly. "Population" is the entire data from which you sample, so I think that is probably not the right term. You can certainly have populations that have bimodal distributions.  If you are looking for a test for number of peaks, there is the Hartigan dip test.

Comment: If you're looking to count the number of modes, there are many approaches. If you search on `modes` or `peaks` you'll turn up a few posts. Note that if you seek an interval estimate, you can really only get a lower bound on the number of modes; there's no upper bound.

Comment: @PeterFlom I think what I mean is groups of subpopulations.  I have a population of data and I want to determine how to detect the number of groups or subpopulations within this data.  I don't necessarily have to get the peak.  I tried to get it using peak/valley detection which isn't robust enough give the sets of data I'm likely to encounter.

Comment: @Glenn_b  This sounds correct.  I'm looking to determine if the data is bimodal, trimodal, etc. and where the centroids of these modes are located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successsfully detected a Level Shift in series like this using Tsay's procedures http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf. His procedures although initially directed to time series are general enough such that when the arima structure is (0,0,0)(0,0,0) it will detect the significant  level shift(s) in the mean. The concept here is akin to single dimension (characteristic) cluster analysis. If you post your data, I will give it a try. I don't know about detecting peaks but they might show up as Pulses (outliers).

EDIT: 5 minutes after receipt of the 6851 ordered values .

Following is a plot of the ordered value [image] with 3 points in time denoted as "L" for Level Shift . The equation developed gives us a clue as to the groupings [image] . it contains arima structure reflecting the orderliness of the data ( low to high ) and is just a filter that allows us to detect the structural breaks. Remember all models are wrong but this model(equation) seems useful. Does it approximately match you "human judgement" ?

group1;   1-1748
group2;   1749-3688
group3;   3689-6166
group4;   6167-6851

Detecting level shifts in this case is detecting change of intercept. The detection of level shifts is an on-or about test and seems to have picked out the primary contrast at 3689 perhaps suggesting a rerun just using the first 3688 and a second run with just the remainder. Clearly this innovative application provides some good results but it seems to warrant further research. Visually there is a change in trend at 1749 suggesting that a new group has formed as the slope of the line has changed.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Single dimension cluster analysis seems like the way to go but I'm only familiar with k-means.  Since k-means requires you to know the number of clusters in advance I cannot use it because I don't know the modality in advance.  I can post my data if you want.  Do you have a format preference?

Comment: single column would be fine ....order the numbers from low to high

Comment: Let me know if this link doesn't work. http://www.mediafire.com/download/zxq8h471msk54vm/data.txt.zip

Comment: malwarebytes doesn't like the website . It is a Norton-like utility that I find very useful. Please put it elsewhere or email it to me.

Comment: I've hosted it on my dropbox account.  Here is the link.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjv2lz8z9bem5au/data.txt.zip  Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for that analysis!  It seems to fit given the data I passed on to you.  Now to implement this in python.  Looks like I'll be reading up on Tsay's procedures.